# How to make "options" persist in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I found out that the "options" function in R doesn't persist through the chunks.

To be specific, I first write down a chunk like

```
options(digits = 15)
```

and then write down a separate chunk like

```
a = 1/2^10
a
```

But the 'digits' option I had set in the previous chunk doesn't work at all and goes back to the default.

I found out that the "options" function works in the specific chunk that it's in, but it is annoying to write down these options in every single chunks.

Is there any way to fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `options` in an arbitrary chunk. They will be valid until they are reset.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r test}
a = 1/2^10
a
```

foo

```{r test2}
op <- options(digits=3)  ## the <- assignment stores default values
a = 1/2^10
a
```

```{r test3}
options(op)  ## re-assign
a = 1/2^10
a
```
````

### Yields

[image]

### Note:

I use `digits=3` here to demonstrate that this works. Note, that `digits=` option considers max. significant digits and discards trailing zeroes.

Consider this:

```
formatC(1/2^10, digits=15, format="f")
# [1] "0.000976562500000"
```

This shows that the five trailing zeroes of your calculation would be discarded. Probably this caused your confusion.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know r setup works for options other than knitr, too. One more thing, what should I do if I want to change the base option in the middle of the document?

Comment: @DayDream Actually even if it's called `setup` it's just an ordinary code chunk. Such a chunk at the very top is useful though to get things together. You may use `options` at any location in your script. See edit to my answer.